# Checking for mouse hover for a certain radius around a point

Tags: c#, forms

I am creating an FPS-like game via C# form.
It is the first game I'm writing, so take it easy :p
Anyway, the main idea is that the program would recognize when user's cursor hovers on a character. 
Now lets say that the character's coordinates are (X,Y) and I want to check if the cursor is within.. a range of 10. 
To check this, I can use 2 conditions of **for** loops, but I believe there is a better way for checking it and I just don't know it.
If you misunderstood what my intention is, post here and I will try to clarify it. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a for loop.
Say the mouse coordinates is (m_x,m_y) while char coordinates is (x,y).
Calculate distance as sqrt((m_x-x)*(m_x-x) + (m_y-y)*(m_y-y)) if the distance is less than 10, then the mouse is in range.

For better running time avoid using sqrt, i.e.,

> if (((m_x-x)*(m_x-x) + (m_y-y)*(m_y-y) <100 )
>     // within range
>     else
>      //outside range